# Simple Java game of a rocket ship flying in space

Tags: java, game, javafx

This is just some code I wrote for a hobby really, I'm trying to get better so please tell me all the bad/weird stuff I've done. Thanks for helping! I've left a little boring code out but most of it is here. [This is what the game looks like (low fps is because of the gif looks way smoother on my PC)](https://giphy.com/gifs/xT9Ignvi760yVScxgY). [Images used (except target but that does nothing rn)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLPEX.jpg)

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        initGame ig = new initGame();
        ig.initUI(stage);

        RocketShip rocketShip = new RocketShip();
        rocketShip.initImageShip();
        rocketShip.setOverallForceNull();

        GraphicsContext gc = ig.gc;
        //fd.render(gc);
        LongValue lastNanoTime = new LongValue(System.nanoTime());
        List<Unitvector> forces = new ArrayList<>();

        MovingObject Alien = new MovingObject();
        Alien.initImage("/home/ed/Pictures/Misc_Photos/Games/target.png");
        Alien.setRandPosition();
        //would be target to hit as yet does nothing

        class timer extends AnimationTimer{
            @Override
            public void handle(long l) {
                double elapsedTime = (l - lastNanoTime.value) / 1000000000.0;
                lastNanoTime.value = l;
                //calcs time since last update DO NOT USE l IN ANIMATIONS!!!
                Unitvector vcNew = new Unitvector();
                //this is the force that acts on the rocketship

                gc.clearRect(0,0,640,480);
                //System.out.println(rot.getVal());
                rotation rot1 = new rotation();
                //interpretBooleans(forces, rocketShip);
                //what keys have been pressed
                if(interpretBooleansNoList(rocketShip)){
                    vcNew = makeNewUnitVector();
                }else{vcNew.initNullVector();}

                rocketShip.drawShip(gc, rot1.getVal());
                //TODO make this an overloadable method
                Alien.drawNonRotated(gc, Alien);


                rocketShip.drawMissile(gc);
                //MO.drawRocks(rocks, gc, rot1.getVal()); //this doesn't work null pointer exception
                //something isn't set right use the SUPER call more

                //rocketShip.updatePos(elapsedTime, forces);

                rocketShip.noListCalculatePos(elapsedTime, vcNew);
                //System.out.println(Alien.checkCollision(rocketShip, Alien));

                rocketShip.updateMissile(elapsedTime);
                //MO.updateRocks(rocks, elapsedTime);

                try {
                    TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(10000);
                    /*
                    slows the animation down- not a very good method though
                    */
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
        timer tim = new timer();
        tim.start();
        handleEvent(ig.getScene(), rocketShip);

        stage.show();
    }
    //to handle multiple key presses
    private BooleanProperty aPressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private BooleanProperty dPressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    private BooleanProperty wPressed = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    private void handleEvent(Scene scene, RocketShip rs){
        rotation rot = new rotation();
        //RocketShip shipRef = new RocketShip();
        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (key)->{
            if(key.getCode() == KeyCode.A){
                //System.out.println("fg" + rot.val);
                aPressed.set(true);
                //rot.decrement();
                //vec.setAccelation(0);
            }
            else if(key.getCode().equals(KeyCode.D)){
                //rot.increment();
                dPressed.set(true);
                //vec.setAccelation(0);
            }
            if(key.getCode().equals(KeyCode.W)){
                //move picture in correct direction of trave
                //or calculate acceleration each time this is used create
                //new unit vector that can act in the direction of travel
                wPressed.set(true);

                //they are not on the same vector
                //System.out.println("fgndfkl");

            }
            if(key.getCode().equals(KeyCode.SPACE)){
                //fire a 'missile'
                rs.fireMissile(rot.getVal());
            }
        });
        scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, (key)->{

            if(key.getCode().equals(KeyCode.A)){
                aPressed.set(false);
            }
            if(key.getCode().equals(KeyCode.D)){
                dPressed.set(false);
            }
            if(key.getCode().equals(KeyCode.W)){
                rs.setIgnition(false);
                wPressed.set(false);
            }
        });
    }
    private void interpretBooleans(List<Unitvector> lst, RocketShip rs){
        rotation rot = new rotation();

        if(aPressed.get()){
            rot.decrement();
        }
        else if(dPressed.get()){
            rot.increment();
        }
        if(wPressed.get()){

            Unitvector vecNew = new Unitvector();
            //create and add a new unitVector to the list

            vecNew.incrementAcceleration(1.5);
            vecNew.calcVelocity(rot.getVal());
            lst.add(vecNew);
            rs.setIgnition(true);
        }
    }
    private boolean interpretBooleansNoList(RocketShip rs){
        rotation rot = new rotation();

        if(aPressed.get()){
            rot.decrement();
        }
        else if(dPressed.get()){
            rot.increment();
        }
        if(wPressed.get()){
            rs.setIgnition(true);
            return true;
            //this is signal that we need a new unitvector force
        }
        return false;
    }
    private Unitvector makeNewUnitVector(){
        //this should not be in main
        rotation rot = new rotation();

        Unitvector vecNew = new Unitvector();
        //create new unitvector (avoids list memory heavy list)

        vecNew.incrementAcceleration(1.5);
        vecNew.calcVelocity(rot.getVal());
        return vecNew;
    }

    private class LongValue{
        long value;
        LongValue(long i){
            value=i;
        }
    }
}
class rotation{
    //this is a bit of a waste
    static double val;
    double getVal(){
        return val;
    }
    void decrement(){
        if(val - 2 < 0){
            val = 360;
        }
        val -= 2;

    }
    void increment(){
        if( val + 2 > 360){
            val = 0;
        }
        val+=2;
    }
}

class initGame {
    Stage mainStage;
    Canvas canvas;
    GraphicsContext gc;
    Group root;
    RocketShip ship = new RocketShip();
    Scene scene;

    initGame() {
        this.mainStage = null;
        this.canvas = null;
        this.gc = null;
        this.root = null;
        this.scene = null;
    }

    void initUI(Stage mainStage) {
        //GameBoard board = new GameBoard();
        //Setting the properties of the rectangle


        this.canvas = new Canvas(boardInfo.width, boardInfo.height);
        //Creating a Group object
        this.root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);


        //canvas image which can draw on with graphic context
        this.gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        //Creating a scene object
        this.scene = new Scene(root);

        //Setting title to the Stage
        mainStage.setTitle("Asteroids");

        //Adding scene to the stage
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
    }
    Scene getScene(){
        return scene;
    }
}
class boardInfo {
    static int width = 640;
    static int height = 480;
}
```

Then the rocket ship class, with others

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class RocketShip extends MovingObject{
    private boolean ignition;
    //this changes which image to disply- if w pressed changes to a rocket with flames
    //altered in event handlers in Main
    private Image afterBurner;
    //the only extra methods this needs are to fire the rockets and have the binary
    //burner or not

    private List<missile> firedMissiles;
    //multiple missiles can be fired from the ship

    RocketShip(){
        firedMissiles = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void initImageShip(){
        File fle = new File("/home/ed/Pictures/Misc_Photos/Games/rocket.png");
        setImage(new Image(fle.toURI().toString()));

        File fle2 = new File("/home/ed/Pictures/Misc_Photos/Games/rocketAfterBurner.png");
        afterBurner = new Image(fle2.toURI().toString());
        setPosition(100, 100);
    }

    void setOverallForceNull(){
        overallForce = new Unitvector();
        overallForce.initNullVector();
    }

    void drawShip(GraphicsContext gc, double rot){

        if(ignition == false)
            drawRotatedImage(gc, img, rot, posX, posY);
        else{
            drawRotatedImage(gc, afterBurner, rot, posX, posY);
        }
    }
    void drawMissile(GraphicsContext gc){
        for(missile mis : firedMissiles){
            //System.out.println(mis.getPosX() + " " + mis.getPosY());
            drawRotatedImage(gc, mis.getImg(), mis.getRotation(), mis.posX,
                    mis.posY);
            //need to rotate this about the same point that the other is rotated around
        }
    }
    void noListCalculatePos(double time, Unitvector force){
        //here we remember the overall force and only multiply it to each new force
        //when a new one is added (user presses a direction key)
        calcOverallForce(force);
        //System.out.println(overallForce.getForceX());

        overallForce.drag();
        posX += overallForce.getForceX() * time;
        posY += overallForce.getForceY() * time;
    }
    void calcOverallForce(Unitvector force){
        //each time direction and acceleration changes add the new vector to the
        //overall force (right word?)
        overallForce.setForceX(force.getForceX() + overallForce.getForceX());
        overallForce.setForceY(force.getForceY() + overallForce.getForceY());
        //System.out.println(force.getForceX() + " " + overallForce.getForceX());
    }

    void updateMissile(double time){
        List<missile> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();
        for(missile ms : firedMissiles){
            //System.out.println(ms.getPosX() + " " + ms.getPosY());
            ms.move(ms.overallForce.getForceX() * time, ms.overallForce.getForceY() * time);
            if(ms.checkOutOfBounds()){
                toRemove.add(ms);
            }
        }
        firedMissiles.removeAll(toRemove);
    }

    public void setIgnition(boolean ignition) {
        this.ignition = ignition;
    }

    void fireMissile(double angle){
        //System.out.println("this has happened");
        missile mis = new missile(this, angle);
        mis.setImg();
        mis.overallForce.setAccelation(250);
        mis.findHead(this);
        mis.overallForce.calcVelocity(angle);
        firedMissiles.add(mis);
    }

}
class Unitvector{
    //will be a unit vector and used to show all the forces acting
    //on the rocket ship
    private double forceX;
    private double forceY;
    private double accelation;

    void calcVelocity(double theta){
        //finds the direction associated with the speed of the object
        //to make a vector
        forceX = accelation * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(theta));
        forceY = accelation * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(theta));
        //unit vector in the direction of the angle
    }
    void drag(){
        forceY *= 0.997;
        forceX *= 0.997;
    }
    public void incrementAcceleration(double i){
        this.accelation += i;
    }

    public double getForceY() {
        return forceY;
    }

    public double getForceX() {
        return forceX;
    }

    public void setAccelation(double accelation) {
        this.accelation = accelation;
    }

    void initNullVector(){
        forceX = 0;
        forceY= 0;
        accelation = 0;
    }

    void setForceX(double nforceX) {
        this.forceX = nforceX;
    }

    void setForceY(double nforceY) {
        this.forceY = nforceY;
    }
}
class missile extends MovingObject{
    //when space is pressed fires a missile according the the angle the rocket ship is
    //currently at
    private double rotation;
    private static double radius;
    double headX;
    double headY;

    missile(RocketShip rocketShip, double rot){
        posX = rocketShip.getPosX() + rocketShip.getWidth();
        posY = rocketShip.getPosY() + rocketShip.getHeight() / 1.5;
        //System.out.println("head is: " + posX + ", " + posY);
        rotation = rot;

        overallForce = new Unitvector();
        overallForce.initNullVector();

        radius = new TrigStuff().findRadius(rocketShip.getPosX() + rocketShip.getWidth() /1.5,
                rocketShip.getPosY() + rocketShip.getHeight() /1.5,
                rocketShip.getPosX(), rocketShip.getPosY());
        //this roughly calculates where the image should be drawn from based on the radius of the ship
        //image

    }
    void setImg(){
        File fle = new File("/home/ed/Pictures/Misc_Photos/Games/missile.png");
        img = new Image(fle.toURI().toString());
    }

    public boolean checkOutOfBounds(){
        return posX < -20 || posX > boardInfo.width + 10
                || posY < -10 || posY > boardInfo.height + 10;
    }

    void move(double valX, double valY){
        //moves the missile according to time * acceleration
        posX += valX;
        posY += valY;
    }
    protected void findHead(MovingObject rS){
        //uses points on a circle around the center of the point of rotation to vaguely
        //start the missile from the nose of the rocket

        //System.out.println(rS.getimHeight() + " " + rS.getimWidth());
        TrigStuff help = new TrigStuff();
        posX = help.findCircleX(rS.getPosX() + 27,
                rotation, radius);
        posY = help.findCircleY(rS.getPosY() + 6,
                rotation, radius);
        //this is hardcoded wank but its the only thing thats vaguely worked
        System.out.println(posX + " " + posY);
    }
    protected void findMissileHead(MovingObject rS){
        //this is probably really wasteful (and doesn't work lol)

        //uses points on a circle around the center of the point of rotation.
        //System.out.println(rS.getimHeight() + " " + rS.getimWidth());
        TrigStuff help = new TrigStuff();
        double missileRadius = help.findRadius(rS.getPosX() + rS.img.getWidth() /1.5,
                rS.getPosY() + rS.img.getHeight() / 1.5, rS.getPosX(), rS.getPosY());

        headX = help.findCircleX(rS.getPosX() + rS.img.getWidth() /1.5,
                rotation, missileRadius);
        headY = help.findCircleY(rS.getPosY() + rS.img.getHeight() / 1.5,
                rotation, missileRadius);
        //this is hardcoded wank but its the only thing thats vaguely worked
        System.out.println(headX + " " + headY);

        //this will be used to find where the head of the missile is to check for collisions
        //with the target
    }
    double getRotation() {
        return rotation;
    }
}
```

And the parent class for the moving objects. Image is rotated every time it is drawn- this seems pretty wasteful to me.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;

class MovingObject {
    //this will be a parent class for rocket ship with positional information
    Image img;
    double posX;
    double posY;
    double width;
    double height;
    Unitvector overallForce;

    void rotate(GraphicsContext gc, double angle, double px, double py) {
        Rotate r = new Rotate(angle, px, py);
        gc.setTransform(r.getMxx(), r.getMyx(), r.getMxy(), r.getMyy(), r.getTx(), r.getTy());
    }
    /**
     * Draws an image on a graphics context.
     *This rotates the entire graphical context- is this efficient
     * The image is drawn at (tlpx, tlpy) rotated by angle pivoted around the point:
     *   (tlpx + image.getWidth() / 2, tlpy + image.getHeight() / 2)
     *
     * @param gc the graphics context the image is to be drawn on.
     * @param angle the angle of rotation.
     * @param tlpx the top left x co-ordinate where the image will be plotted (in canvas co-ordinates).
     * @param tlpy the top left y co-ordinate where the image will be plotted (in canvas co-ordinates).
     */
    void drawRotatedImage(GraphicsContext gc, Image image, double angle, double tlpx, double tlpy) {
        gc.save(); // saves the current state on stack, including the current transform
        //System.out.println(tlpx + image.getWidth() / 1.5 + " s" + (tlpy + image.getHeight() / 1.5));
        rotate(gc, angle, tlpx + image.getWidth() / 1.5, tlpy + image.getHeight() / 1.5);
        gc.drawImage(image, tlpx, tlpy);
        gc.restore(); // back to original state (before rotation)
    }
    void initImage(String fileName){
        File fle = new File(fileName);
        setImage(new Image(fle.toURI().toString()));
    }
    void setImage(Image i) {
        this.img = i;
        width = i.getWidth();
        height = i.getHeight();
    }

    void drawNonRotated(GraphicsContext gc, MovingObject MO){
        gc.drawImage(MO.img, MO.posX, MO.posY);
    }
    protected void setPosition(int x, int y){
        posX = x;
        posY = y;
    }
    protected void setRandPosition(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        posX = rand.nextInt(440);
        posY = rand.nextInt(600);
        System.out.println(posY + " " + posX);
    }

    void setPosX(double coord){
        posX = coord;
    }
    void setPosY(double coord){
        posY = coord;
    }


    Image getImg() {
        return img;
    }
    double getWidth(){
        return width;
    }
    double getHeight(){
        return height;
    }

    boolean checkCollision(MovingObject collider, MovingObject colidee){
        //horrible English

        //issue here is that the fired missile will be rotated doesn't
        //work at all right now- hard to track position of front of missile                                                                    
        if(collider.getPosX() <= colidee.getPosX() + colidee.getWidth() &&
                collider.getPosX() >= colidee.getPosX() &&
                collider.getPosY() <= colidee.getPosY() + colidee.getHeight() &&
                collider.getPosY() >= colidee.getPosY()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    double getPosX() {
        return posX;
    }

    double getPosY() {
        return posY;
    }
}
```

And some maths

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;

public class TrigStuff {
    //this calculates the trajectory of where the ship needs to go
    private void rotate(GraphicsContext gc, double angle, double px, double py) {
        Rotate r = new Rotate(angle, px, py);
        gc.setTransform(r.getMxx(), r.getMyx(), r.getMxy(), r.getMyy(), r.getTx(), r.getTy());
    }
    /**
     * Draws an image on a graphics context.
     *
     * The image is drawn at (tlpx, tlpy) rotated by angle pivoted around the point:
     *   (tlpx + image.getWidth() / 2, tlpy + image.getHeight() / 2)
     *
     * @param gc the graphics context the image is to be drawn on.
     * @param angle the angle of rotation.
     * @param tlpx the top left x co-ordinate where the image will be plotted (in canvas co-ordinates).
     * @param tlpy the top left y co-ordinate where the image will be plotted (in canvas co-ordinates).
     */
    private void drawRotatedImage(GraphicsContext gc, Image image, double angle, double tlpx, double tlpy) {
        gc.save(); // saves the current state on stack, including the current transform
        rotate(gc, angle, tlpx + image.getWidth() / 1.5, tlpy + image.getHeight() / 1.5);
        gc.drawImage(image, tlpx, tlpy);
        gc.restore(); // back to original state (before rotation)
    //todo get rid of this method and wherever it is called 
    }
    double findRotatedX(double PointofRotX, double PointofRotY, double angle,
                        double PointTOMoveX, double PointToMoveY){
        //the point of rotation is actually confusingly posX + image width /1.5

        //X=BX+(AX−BX)cosϕ−(AY−BY)sinϕ B is point of rotation
        return PointofRotX + (PointTOMoveX - PointofRotX) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))
                - (PointToMoveY - PointofRotY) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
    }
    double findRotatedY(double PointofRotX, double PointofRotY, double angle,
                        double PointTOMoveX, double PointToMoveY){
        //Y=BY+(AX−BX)sinϕ+(AY−BY)cosϕ B is point of rotation
        return PointofRotY + (PointofRotX - PointofRotX) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle))
                - (PointToMoveY - PointofRotY) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
    }
    double findCircleX(double PointofRotX, double angle,
                       double radius){
        //its actually a circle with centre PoR and radius need to flip for screen coords
        return (radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle))) + PointofRotX;
    }
    double findCircleY(double PointofRotY, double angle,
                       double radius) {
        //its actually a circle with centre PoR and radius need to flip for screen coords
        //this doesn't work and probably never will
        return radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) + PointofRotY;
    }
    double findRadius(double xc, double yc, double xe, double ye){
        //where xc/yc is the center points, and xe ye are edge
        //(x-a)**2 + (y-b)**2 = r**
        double raduisSq = Math.pow((xe-xc), 2) + Math.pow((ye-yc), 2);
        return Math.sqrt(raduisSq);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the "boring code" is not too much you could include it here so that we can compile and run your game locally.

Comment: apologies, just included everything (there's some unused methods in there but just ignore them)

Comment: No apologies needed, since you are still new here. :)

Answer (score 3):

1. All constants should be declared in a final variable.

   ```
   final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/home/ed/Pictures/Misc_Photos/Games/";
   final String TARGET_IMAGE_FILENAME = "target.png";
   File file = new File(IMAGE_DIRECTORY + TARGET_IMAGE_FILENAME);
   ```
2. Methods and classes should have a documentary comment for readability.
3. Avoid using one letter variable, it will lead to confusion especially when your program grew larger.

   ```
   Rotate r = new Rotate();
   ```

Should be:

```
Rotate rotate = new Rotate();
```